# If condition isn't met, raise error, if not, run procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to have an error display if the conditions aren't met. Both `@variable1` and `@variable2` can take only take few values.

Here's my code:

```
ALTER PROC Test
    (@Variable1 AS INT,
     @Variable2 AS CHAR(2))
AS
    DECLARE @err_message nvarchar(max)

    IF @Variable1 <> 1 OR @Variable1 <> 2 OR @Variable1 <> 3
        SET @err_message = 'Not available'

    BEGIN
        RAISEERROR (@err_message,16,1)
    END

    IF @Variable2 <> 'IT'
        SET @err_message = 'Not IT'

    BEGIN
        RAISEERROR (@err_message,16,1)
    END

    RUN PROCEDURE
```

I get an error for `RAISEERROR`

> Incorrect syntax. Expecting conversation

and with the second `IF` statement.

Comment: You can thank Microsoft for saving a vowel: [`RaIsError`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx). Just think of it as a Sun God Boo Boo. And you probably want the `SET` statements _inside_ the `BEGIN`/`END` blocks. Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. `tsql` does not specify the software.

Comment: Thanks! Will use the appropriate tags next time. I don't think I'm the only one that got caught with the extra E in RaisError ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simpler and correct to use `NOT IN`:

```
IF @Variable1 NOT IN (1, 2, 3)
    BEGIN
        SET @err_message = 'Not available'
        RAISERROR(@err_message, 16, 1)
    END;


IF @Variable2 <> 'IT'
    BEGIN
        SET @err_message = 'Not IT'
        RAISERROR(@err_message, 16, 1)
    END;
```

Your first condition will always generate an error.

Comment: It's actually just `RAISERROR` - only one "E" in the middle there - no one really knows why, but that's the case for now :-)